# How does the Baja California Sur sustainability tax work?

Tags: mexico, taxes, los-cabos

When flying into San Jose del Cabo airport, I've been given a flyer about a new sustainability tax with a link to [Travelerfundbcs.gob.mx](https://www.travelerfundbcs.gob.mx/). According to the LA Times [it is voluntary](https://www.latimes.com/travel/story/2019-11-06/los-cabos-mexico-donation-sustainability-airport):

> Travelers arriving at Los Cabos International Airport will be asked for about $18 (350 pesos) each starting Saturday. But local officials say this isn’t a tax. It’s a request for a **voluntary contribution** to benefit a new Fund for a Sustainable Baja California Sur.
>
> Under the new program, officials said, the San José del Cabo airport will feature kiosks encouraging visitors to contribute at the kiosk or through online payments.
>
> Isidro Jordán Moyrón, secretary of finance for the State of Baja California Sur, said in a prepared statement that the new effort is not “entry tax” and that “**visitors will not be forced or unduly coerced into making a contribution**.”

However the [official website](https://www.travelerfundbcs.gob.mx/Home/Faq) doesn't mention that it's voluntary:

> As such, all international visitors **must** make a one time payment of $ 350 Mexican Pesos to the Fund.

Is it actually voluntary? Are there any penalties for not paying this tax?

Comment: What does the flyer say?

Comment: Also, it seems misleading to call it a "tax" in your title and question, when it looks like all your information so far is that it's not a tax.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'll take a photo later if I can find it, but it was vague too. If it's not mandatory then it's not a tax. If it is then it's a tax :)

Comment: Well, the government seems to be saying very explicitly that it's not mandatory.  Is there reason to doubt them?

Comment: Also, if you flew there recently (after Nov 9), the charge would have been in effect, so presumably you know whether you had to pay it or not?  Are you planning to answer your own question?

Comment: @NateEldredge I did not have to pay but the flyer somehow made it look like I'll get into trouble if I don't.

Comment: There's an apparently official website, https://www.travelerfundbcs.gob.mx/, which says that "all international visitors *must*" make the payment.  The Spanish has the same sense ("deben pagar").  So now I understand why there is confusion.

Comment: I recall discussing this with someone here in Baja (not Sur) a few months ago - something along the lines of it's mandatory for international visitors, and not mandatory for Mexicans.  And that they may (or may not) ask for it at police/military/INM checkpoints.  I can't back anything up with a source though, it was just a conversation

Comment: @Midavalo I've emailed the contact on their official website, let's see what they say. I wouldn't mind paying if it's actually mandatory, but don't want to spend money needlessly if it's not.

Comment: @Midavalo ok, their email system is down :) "Your message wasn't delivered to contact@travelerfundbcs.gob.mx because the address couldn't be found or is unable to receive email."

Comment: @JonathanReez [This article](https://elfinanciero.com.mx/nacional/baja-california-sur-cobrara-un-impuesto-especifico-a-turistas-extranjeros) (in Spanish) calls it a Tax and says it's to be collected by airlines or via kiosk at the airport.  Cruise passengers are exempt.

Comment: @ColumbiasaysReinstateMonica: It can mean either, according to my understanding and the dictionaries I checked.  But I would defer to a native or more expert speaker.

Comment: @RobertColumbia I would translate it as "must" also, and the English translation on that government website says "must".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've left from Cabo Airport and no one asked me anything about paying this tax. This combined with the fact that the Secretary of Finance describes the tax as optional makes me believe that it is indeed not mandatory.

Therefore I can advise avoiding to pay this tax/fee unless you really want to contribute to this fund.

Comment: Are you certain that it wasn't imposed as an airport tax on your ticket?

Comment: @phoog definitely not, as travelers were explicitly asked to pay online or at the kiosks